# Prestashop - How to display error in productSave hook

Tags: prestashop

Like mentioned in the title how can i display error called in `productSave` hook? presta version is 1.7.6.x

I've tried with

```
Tools::displayError($this->l('error message')); // but this one is only visible in debug mode
```

I will be thankful for help with this,

Cheers, Wiktor

Answer (score 0):

try in new file on site root, activate error on you website.

In file :

```
<?php
    include('config/config.inc.php');

    $idP = 705;

    $prod = new Product($idP);
    $prod->weight = '0';
    dump($prod->save());
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested these before But it probably works

```
    $this->jsonError('custom error');
```

OR

```
    if (isset($error)) {
        $json = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => $error,
        );
    }

    die(json_encode($json));
```